# C++ Goto variable

Tags: c++, variables, goto

Is there a way to call a goto statement using a variable in the place of a label name?

I'm looking for something similar to this (this doesn't work for me):

```
// std::string or some other type that could represent a label
void callVariable(std::string name){
    goto name;
}

int main(){
    first:
    std::cout << "Hi";
    callVariable(first);

    return 0;
}
```

I am not actually using this, I am more interested in learning.

Comment: gotos are bad mkay?

Comment: I teach that a goto can always be replaced by a function call and a little rewrite, but this is an interesting construct -- dynamic branching I guess. I'd never use it but it's fun to talk about.

Comment: Sometimes beginners ask interesting questions.   That is an interesting approach.    But what you want is a `switch` statement.

Comment: @nicomp Yeah I totally understand that gotos are not optimal in almost all use-cases. I am approaching this from more of a learning standpoint, wondering how this could be done.

Comment: @nicomp gotos are well adapted for old, ugly and outdated code. sure it can save you a lot of time in that case. It's just that today with features like lamdas, you barely need it anymore. But as they exist, it's important to know them, and learn why not use them.

Comment: FORTRAN had a computed go to. Don't know if it still does.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Someone, possibly you, once mentioned Intercal's computed `COMEFROM`. :) <url: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INTERCAL#Control_structures>

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf -- I hadn't seen that before. Very avant garde. I did see an article about BASIC once that mentioned COMEFROM, as well as WHOA, which you were supposed to use to warn the compiler to slow down for some really tricky code.

Comment: @Pete Becker - From memory, computed goto was put onto the obsolescent list in Fortran 95.   I'm not sure if it has been deleted in a later standard.

Comment: goto are great when you are programatically generating code, for example for a language parser. When humans don't need to manually maintain the code, goto can help a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you make a computed goto in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45380073/can-you-make-a-computed-goto-in-c)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes and no. There's no such standard language feature, but it is a [compiler extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) in at least GCC:

```
int main() {
    void* label;

    first:
    std::cout << "Hi";
    label = &&first;
    goto *label;
}
```

That said, I'd have to think hard for a use case where this is better than any standard alternatives.

Comment: plusone . . . easily the coolest hack I've seen all year.  Not something I would (or should) ever use but still pretty neat.

Comment: @sparc_spread IMHO "clever" and "tricky" code that will confuse most readers is *not* a good thing. Leave "clever" to the compiler and write clear, readable code. Trying to be too clever and using obscure corners of the language is IMHO more a sign of a bad programmer than anything else..

Comment: @sparc_spread: This is not a hack. It's a language extension.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl That's what the "not  . . . would (or should) ever use" disclaimer part was about :-)

Comment: @Anonymous, The function would have to be a macro. `goto` doesn't work across different functions.

Comment: @chris For a possible use case: I can think of one. This would serve to efficiently execute 2 or more concurrent (in logic only) finite state machines. You store the state of each FSM in a variable, and from time to time, you do a sort of context switch where you jump from one fsm to another, but directly at the state it was in the previous time. Then you "return" to the main fsm

Answer (score 4):

You ask:

> **”** Is there a way to call a goto statement using a variable in the place of a label name?

Yes, the feature in C++ that provides that effect is called `switch`. It doesn't syntactically involve the word `goto`. But it jumps to a label specified by a variable, and so, with it you can emulate all kinds of dirty `goto`-based code, including early Basic's `on ... goto ...`.

---

Your hypothetical example

```
int main(){
    first:
    std::cout << "Hi";
    callVariable(first);

    return 0;
}
```

… looks like this in real C++:

```
#define CALL_VARIABLE( where ) next_jump = where; break;

auto main()
    -> int
{
    enum Label {first, second, third};
    Label next_jump = first;
    for( ;; ) switch( next_jump )
    {
    case first:
        std::cout << "Hi";
        CALL_VARIABLE( first );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: no. And why would you want this? Just stop using `goto` already.

Maybe (just guessing) what you want is a `std::function` or a `switch` instead..

Comment: `goto` isn't always bad, some constructs for embedded to allow a program to always have the same exit point make the code neater and safer (especially when exceptions are not available or too expensive) .

Comment: Sure, for C code it can be useful for "single-exit-point-cleanup" blocks and other similar constructs. I'm not trying to say it is *always* bad; just that for C++ code there are usually better alternatives. I've done enough Linux kernel patches to recognize that (especially) in C it can be useful for exit blocks.. but I'd hessitate to use it in modern C++.

Answer (score 2):

this is a simple macro solution:

```
#define CALL_VARIALBLE(name) goto name;

int main(){
    first:
    std::cout << "Hi";
    CALL_VARIALBLE(first);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't `goto` a dynamic location.

But you can have a look at POSIX [`setjmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csetjmp/setjmp/)/[`longjmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csetjmp/longjmp/), which can be used to jump to a predefined location in your application. MSVC also supports it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

static jmp_buf buf;

void second(void) {
    printf("second\n");         // prints
    longjmp(buf,1);             // jumps back to where setjmp was called - making setjmp now return 1
}

void first(void) {
    second();
    printf("first\n");          // does not print
}

int main() {   
    if (!setjmp(buf))
        first();                // when executed, setjmp returned 0
    else                        // when longjmp jumps back, setjmp returns 1
        printf("main\n");       // prints

    return 0;
}
```